# How to use the sandbox user on MacOS app to test IAP?

Tags: macos, in-app-purchase

As usual, all the existing answers on Stackoverflow relate to iOS and nothing is out there for MacOS.

- I have signed out of Mac AppStore.
- When I try to attempt a IAP purchase on my app I get this error message shown:

> Account Not In This Store Your account is not valid for use in the
>   U.S. store.
>
> You must switch to the U.K. store before purchasing.
>
> [Environment: Sandbox]

I have created fresh Sandbox users, but the app is not asking me to enter them. And based on the documentation of Apple I shouldn't enter them into the AppStore login or I get them wasted.

I have deleted the `~/Library/Containers/app-bundle-id`, rebooted the dev machine and cleared once again the build folder.  But I can't get it working.

How do I get a prompt for entering the sandbox user?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: When you enter the sandbox user in App Store Connect, i think you need to specify the App Store territory to your current App Store region.

Comment: @Houman did you ever figure this problem out? I am having the same problem too and stuck :(

Comment: @PranoyC It was very painful. I ended up creating a new user on mac and login there and setup Xcode to get prompted again.  Afterwards I realised there is actually an easier way. Go to KeyChain and delete every key that your app has created there.  Clean the build and recompile. Then try again, and it should prompt again.

Comment: @Houman how do I find every key my app has created in the keychain?

Comment: I mean the ones that you created manually via code.  You usually have to define a name for the key group.